# No display but touch screen working on Samsung Galaxy Gio

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-gio

I have Android 2.3.3 Samsung Galaxy Gio phone.

From past few days there is no display on the device. Rest other functions works fine including touch screen (I can unlock).

Not sure if its a software issue or hardware problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off/on? Removing battery? Connecting to charger (to know if you see a charge indicator) both off and on? Removing microSD card? Connecting to computer?

Comment: Hi Francisco, I tried all as mentioned by you way, but no luck... when i boot it the screen changes color from dark to little light (like something light-up in background) that's it..